# Store SMTP user data encrypted?

Tags: php, laravel, smtp

I am currently developing a CRM app. This app enables people to create contacts and save them. There is also the option to send emails.

I've looked into PHP. I am working with Laravel. My database structure is quite easy:

```
Table: emails
id (integer)
server (varchar)
username (varchar)
password (varchar)
time_added (timestamp)
```

I did not find any other way connecting to a given SMTP server other than saving the plain data. This is why  I wanted to ask if anyone knows a way of encrypting that data, saving user passwords without the risk of getting exposed?

It is extremely important for us, as sending emails from provided accounts is one of the core features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel provides the [encryption](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/encryption) methods via the Crypt facade and is very easy to use:

```
$enc = Crypt::encryptString('password'); // returns AES encrypted string
$password = Crypt::decryptString($enc);  // returns decrypted string
```

However, there's always a risk of getting exposed.  Encryption won't protect against everything.  Application level encryption in the database protects leaks from the database server or database backups but won't protect against unauthorized access to your application server.

Comment: Oh thanks. I just knew about hashing methods from laravel. I was wondering: Do you know if there is a way in the SMTP protocol of saving some kind of access key, as in oauth2, instead of saving clear passwords?

Comment: There are oauth implementations for SMTP, but I doubt they are widely supported.  You'll likely have to store user/password combinations for the majority of users, but you may just to recommend your clients provide a separate login for your service.

Comment: Alright cool! Big thanks for the encryption heads up. Cheers!

Comment: You could also use encrypt() and decrypt() helper methods which is equivalent to the ones listed above.